# Manipulating inequalities and probabilities

Tags: probability

We have the Chebychev's inequality $$\mathrm{P}\left(|X - \mu| \ge k\sigma\right) \le \frac{1}{k^{2}}$$ which tells us $\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ is the upper bound. How do we find the lower bound of this probability using this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower bound is zero. Most of the time, you can construct examples that hit these bounds exactly. E.g., a uniform distribution has support on $\mu \pm \sigma \sqrt{3}$, so it places zero probability for $k\ge \sqrt{3}$. But Chebyshev's inequality does not know about it, and that's not its job, anyway. On the other boundary, as far as I recall, Chebyshev's inequality is exact for a two-point mass distribution when $k$ is aligned to hit these masses, so it cannot be improved, either.

Comment: Oh right. So if we want to find the lower bound of $$\mathrm{P}(X > 100) = \mathrm{P}\left( \left|X - \frac{500}{3}\right| > \frac{200}{3}\right)$$ using Chebychev's inequality how do we do this? (Note: $X\sim \mathrm{B}(1000, \frac{1}{6})$)